# Unexpected token for TypeScript decorator

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest, babel-jest

I want to test some code which uses the newly added decorators in TypeScript 5.0 (not experimental decorators), how can I make Jest interpret that code?

I get `SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token` when it meets a `@`

My `jest.config.js` looks like this

```
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(ts|tsx)?$': ['ts-jest', {
      tsConfig: 'tsconfig.esm.json'
    }],
    "^.+\\.(js|jsx)$": "babel-jest",
  }
};
```

`tsconfig.esm.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "esnext",
    "outDir": "dist/esm",
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "declarationDir": "dist/types",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "moduleResolution": "nodenext",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["src/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src/*.ts","src/**/*.ts", "test/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

and `babel.config.js`

```
module.exports = {presets: ['@babel/preset-env']}
```

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm not using `experimental decorators`, I'm using the native decorators included in typescript 5.0^

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Jest with [SWC](https://swc.rs/) and I had the same issue (same error).
And what helped, was creating a [".swcrc" file](https://swc.rs/docs/configuration/compilation#jsctransformlegacydecorator) with this content:

```json
{
  "jsc": {
    "parser": {
      "syntax": "typescript",
      "decorators": true
    },
    "transform": {
      "legacyDecorator": true
    }
  }
}
```

And the SWC has support for [stage 3 decorators](https://swc.rs/docs/configuration/compilation#jsctransformdecoratorversion) too!